# Errors installing Imaging Modules for Python 2.7 on Mac OSX 10.6

Tags: python, gcc, installation, scipy

I'm trying to install scikits.images and Imaging-1.1.7 (from the Python Imaging Library) on Python 2.7.1 on Snow Leopard.  I have Numpy and Scipy installed already.  I just need some way to visualize an array of pixel data [following this example](http://troylee.posterous.com/data-visualization-in-python-using-scipy-0), but I keep getting install errors as below.

My gcc-4.0 files are within /Developer-old/usr/bin but I symlinked /usr/bin/gcc-4.0 to that directory.

```
$ python setup.py install
running install
running build
running build_py
running build_ext
--- using frameworks at /System/Library/Frameworks
building '_imaging' extension
gcc-4.0 -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -arch ppc -arch i386 -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -O3 -IlibImaging -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include -I/usr/local/include -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -c _imaging.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.3-fat-2.7/_imaging.o
In file included from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7/Python.h:19,
                 from _imaging.c:75:
/Developer-old/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-apple-darwin10/4.0.1/include/limits.h:10:25: error: limits.h: No such file or directory
In file included from _imaging.c:75:
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7/Python.h:33:19: error: stdio.h: No such file or directory
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7/Python.h:35:5: error: #error "Python.h requires that stdio.h define NULL."
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7/Python.h:38:20: error: string.h: No such file or directory
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7/Python.h:40:19: error: errno.h: No such file or directory
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7/Python.h:42:20: error: stdlib.h: No such file or directory
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7/Python.h:44:20: error: unistd.h: No such file or directory
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7/Python.h:56:20: error: assert.h: No such file or directory
In file included from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7/Python.h:58,
                 from _imaging.c:75:
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7/pyport.h:9:22: error: inttypes.h: No such file or directory
In file included from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7/Python.h:58,
                 from _imaging.c:75:
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7/pyport.h:170: error: syntax error before ‘Py_ssize_t’
...
...
and so on
...
...
_imaging.c:3147: warning: data definition has no type or storage class
_imaging.c:3149: error: syntax error before ‘*’ token
_imaging.c:3149: error: syntax error before ‘*’ token
_imaging.c:3149: warning: data definition has no type or storage class
_imaging.c:3150: error: syntax error before ‘*’ token
_imaging.c:3150: error: syntax error before ‘*’ token
_imaging.c:3150: warning: data definition has no type or storage class
_imaging.c:3152: error: array type has incomplete element type
_imaging.c:3155: error: syntax error before ‘_blend’
_imaging.c:3156: error: syntax error before ‘_fill’
_imaging.c:3157: error: syntax error before ‘_new’
_imaging.c:3159: error: syntax error before ‘_getcount’
_imaging.c:3162: error: syntax error before ‘_convert2’
_imaging.c:3163: error: syntax error before ‘_copy2’
_imaging.c:3166: error: syntax error before ‘PyImaging_BitDecoderNew’
_imaging.c:3167: error: syntax error before ‘PyImaging_EpsEncoderNew’
_imaging.c:3168: error: syntax error before ‘PyImaging_FliDecoderNew’
_imaging.c:3169: error: syntax error before ‘PyImaging_GifDecoderNew’
_imaging.c:3170: error: syntax error before ‘PyImaging_GifEncoderNew’
_imaging.c:3171: error: syntax error before ‘PyImaging_HexDecoderNew’
_imaging.c:3172: error: syntax error before ‘PyImaging_EpsEncoderNew’
_imaging.c:3177: error: syntax error before ‘PyImaging_TiffLzwDecoderNew’
_imaging.c:3178: error: syntax error before ‘PyImaging_MspDecoderNew’
_imaging.c:3179: error: syntax error before ‘PyImaging_PackbitsDecoderNew’
_imaging.c:3180: error: syntax error before ‘PyImaging_PcdDecoderNew’
_imaging.c:3181: error: syntax error before ‘PyImaging_PcxDecoderNew’
_imaging.c:3182: error: syntax error before ‘PyImaging_PcxEncoderNew’
...
...
lipo: can't figure out the architecture type of:   /var/folders/Mk/MkDxFxURFZmLg+gkCGdO9U+++TM/-Tmp-//ccsfzTIz.out
error: command 'gcc-4.0' failed with exit status 1
```

Am I simply missing some C header files?  I also tried installing Cython because I read somewhere that I need it, but I get the same errors when trying to run "setup.py install" in the Cython folder.  I don't know how to proceed from here...  any help would be appreciated, thanks!

------------- UPDATE ---------------

Well, this really sucked but I couldn't for the life of me get it to work on my Mac.  I ended up borrowing a Windows machine and installing it on that instead, and it worked there.  Boo.

Comment: I also noticed there are two slashes in the pathname on the "lipo: can't figure out..." line.  Looks like that pathname was produced programmatically though.

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo ln -s /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.7.sdk/usr/include/ /usr/include
```

worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

In Maverick, running the following command helped

```
sudo ln -s /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk/usr/include/ /usr/include
```

Answer (score 0):

have you checked that this file exists?

/Developer-old/usr/lib/gcc/i686-apple-darwin10/4.0.1/include/limits.h

Comment: Yep I've checked, and that file exists.
So does /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7/Python.h, and /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7/pyport.h

Comment: @zephyr I'm getting those same errors, and I DON'T have that file... what do I do?